# canvas.toDataURL() not returning full image - it crops top of it

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, base64, html2canvas

```
I am using canvas2html to convert one of my sections:


 <div className="plan-businessInfo" id="businessInfo-main">
          .
          .
          .
     //SOME JSX//
        </div>
```

into base64 string. Here is the method I am using:

```
const onExportClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const businessInfo = document.getElementById("businessInfo-main");
    html2canvas(businessInfo).then(canvas => {
      const imgData = canvas.toDataURL();
      const doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
      console.log(imgData); // GETTING IMAGE string

      // GETTING PDF PAGE SIZE
      const widthPDF = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
      const heightPDF = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight();

        //ADDDING IMAGE WITH SIZE ON THE PDF PAGE
        doc.addImage(
          imgData,
          "png",
          0,
          0,
          widthPDF /**width */,
          heightPDF /**heigth */
        );


      doc.save("abc.pdf");
    });
  };
```

The problem is that image looks awful in the PDF and also base64 string is not full.

1. Here is how the section looks like in the site:

[image]

2. Here is how online base64-to-image parser is displaying image (https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter):

[image]

3. Here is how it looks in PDF:

[image]

First any ideas why base64 string is not completed? 
Bonus question is how to fit it in PDF when it is full?